# Salesforce Error - 1800: There was a problem in setting up your remote access

Tags: oauth

I am new to salesforce and I just was done with setting up Mavensmate Desktop with Sublime Text 3. I am trying to create a new project where I have given the correct credentials to connect to my dev sandbox. After successfully authenticating through salesforce authenticator mobile app, I Allow the Mavensmate to access all of my salesforce basic info and permissions. Once done, I am seeing "redirecting...." for a long time and after that, i am seeing only this error message:

> We can't authorize you because of an OAuth error. For more information, contact your Salesforce administrator.
>   1800: There was a problem in setting up your remote access

Can some one please advise on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I got it working now. There is a permission set called "Developer console Access" ( this permission set includes the Apex, visualforce related permissions that are needed) that has to be created and assigned to the user. Only then you would have the Mavensmate API connecting to salesforce.

Comment: I got this to work by adding the '2FA for API' perm set, btw.