# Sandbox OAuth Error 1800 through VS Code, CLI, and MavensMate

Tags: oauth, mavensmate, cli

I'm trying to sign into a sandbox org, but I'm getting an error when running through the OAuth flow:

```
We can't authorize you because of an OAuth error. 
For more information, contact your Salesforce administrator.
1800 : There was a problem in setting up your remote access
```

I've tried logging in through the CLI (Using command `sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://test.salesforce.com`), MavensMate (selecting Sandbox), and VS Code. All give me the same error. Workbench seems to sign in just fine. Has anyone else had this error?

Comment: What does your [Login History](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/users_login_history.htm) say about this, if anything? Any errors there? Do you get any additional responses (typically in JSON format) that we can look at?

Comment: Looks like when I tried to log in through the CLI, login history shows Status "Success" with HTTP Method "Unknown." The only error it gives me is the one posted above ([see image](https://imgur.com/6LoZDjY)), and the CLI is hung on the login command as if it's still waiting for me to log in.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct permissions? [This question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/155927) suggests it may be a permission issue. Also, I've read that resetting your password may help (why? I don't know, but that's what was said.) Try it out and let us know if either solution helps.

Comment: I've reset the password and it didn't work, and I have a permission set attached to my user with Modify All Data, Author Apex, API Enabled, Manage Connected Apps, and Modify Metadata all enabled, which didn't work either.

Comment: I created a brand new Developer Sandbox and it works. This issue seems to only happen after a refresh.

Comment: I deleted the partial org and recreated it from scratch with a different name, but I'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Mavens remembers old sandbox somehow, I had this problem before and had to edit the config file of the org each time it refreshed. I had posted the question and answer in MM github but I can't find it now but basically.

In the config folder in the .settings file there is a line for "instanceUrl". Update that and then save and it will work for you.

Comment: would this cause the issue of logging in directly through the SFDX CLI, being it's not using MavensMate?

Comment: Do you still have mm plug-in installed? It might still be trying to connect through it.

Comment: Uninstalled MavensMate and had the same issue running the command above.